# Image control, override the method that download the image from an uri

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I'm building a universal app for windows phone 8.1.

I need to download an image from an uri, in the xaml I generally do something like this

```
<Image Source="http://www.examlpe.com/img.png" />
```

but this time i need to add some parameter to the header of the http request otherwise the server doesn't allow me to download the image.

I'm thinking about to extending the image control with a dependency property that has an http request with all the correct header parameter to download the image.

My question is:

There is a better solution to achieve this result?

**Edit**

this is the code that i'm using now

```
public class ImageUriExtension : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageUriProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ImageUri", typeof(string), typeof(ImageUriExtension), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty, OnUriChanged));

    public static string GetImageUri(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(ImageUriProperty);
    }

    public static void SetImageUri(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ImageUriProperty, value);
    }

    private static async void OnUriChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var source = d as Image;
        var path = e.NewValue as string;
        var uri = new Uri(NetConfig.baseUrl + path);
        var stream = await RestClient.DownloadFile(uri);

        var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
        await bitmap.SetSourceAsync(stream);

        source.Source = bitmap; 
    }
}
```

and this is the xaml

```
<Image local:ImageUriExtension.ImageUri="{Binding url}" />
```

Comment: I think this is a pretty good solution. Maybe you could add a `CancelationToken` for cancelling the download if the uri changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, since `<Image />` is sealed, you cannot derive from it. Your best alternative is to extend it with attached properties exactly as you have indicated. Another alternative would be to use a behavior, but there's no point. It would not work "better" than an attached property. Good work.